# Convert OpenGL HQX shader to LibGDX

Tags: libgdx, glsl, shader

I was getting in to shaders for LibGDX and noticed there are some attributes that are only being used in LibGDX.

The standard Vertex and Fragment shaders from https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Shaders work perfect and gets applied to my SpriteBatch.

When i try to use a HQX shader like https://github.com/SupSuper/OpenXcom/blob/master/bin/common/Shaders/HQ2x.OpenGL.shader i get a lot of errors.

Probably because i need to send some LibGDX dependant variables to the shader but i can't find out which that should be.

I'd like to use these shaders on desktops with large screens so the game keeps looking great on these screens.

I used this code to load the shader:

`try {
    shaderProgram = new ShaderProgram(Gdx.files.internal("vertex.glsl").readString(), Gdx.files.internal("fragment.glsl").readString());
    shaderProgram.pedantic = false;
    System.out.println("Shader Log:");
    System.out.println(shaderProgram.getLog());
} catch(Exception ex) { }`

The Shader Log outputs:
`No errors.`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you drawing with it? Did you construct a Mesh or are you using SpriteBatch? I assume you are using the texture from a FrameBuffer?

Comment: I'am using `batch.setShader(shaderProgram);` in my render() method so the shaders get applied to the SpriteBatch, then i draw all of my textures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a post processing shader, so your flow should go like this:

1. Draw your scene to a FBO at pixel perfect resolution using SpriteBatch's default shader.
2. Draw the FBO's texture to the screen's frame buffer using the upscaling shader. You can do this with SpriteBatch if you modify the shader to match the attributes and uniforms that SpriteBatch uses. (You could alternatively create a simple mesh with the attribute names that the shader expects, but SpriteBatch is probably easiest.)

First of all, we are not using a typical shader with SpriteBatch so you need to call `ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;` somewhere before loading anything.

Now you need a FrameBuffer at the right size. It should be sized for your sprites to be pixel perfect (one pixel of texture scales to one pixel of world). Something like this:

```
public void resize (int width, int height){
    float ratio = (float)width / (float) height;
    int gameWidth = (int)(GAME_HEIGHT / ratio);
    boolean needNewFrameBuffer = false;
    if (frameBuffer != null && (frameBuffer.getWidth() != gameWidth || frameBuffer.getHeight() != GAME_HEIGHT)){
        frameBuffer.dispose();
        needNewFrameBuffer = true;
    }
    if (frameBuffer == null || needNewFrameBuffer)
        frameBuffer = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, gameWidth, GAME_HEIGHT);

    camera.viewportWidth = gameWidth;
    camera.viewportHeight = GAME_HEIGHT;
    camera.update();
}
```

Then you can draw to the frame buffer as if it's your screen. And after that, you draw the frame buffer's texture to the screen.

```
public void render (){
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    frameBuffer.begin();
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.setShader(null); //use default shader
    batch.begin();
    //draw your game
    batch.end();

    frameBuffer.end();

    batch.setShader(upscaleShader);
    batch.begin();
    upscaleShader.setUniformf("rubyTextureSize", frameBuffer.getWidth(), frameBuffer.getHeight());//this is the uniform in your shader. I assume it's wanting the scene size in pixels
    batch.draw(frameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), -1, 1, 2, -2); //full screen quad for no projection matrix, with Y flipped as needed for frame buffer textures
    batch.end();
}
```

There are also some changes you need to make to your shader so it will work with OpenGL ES, and because SpriteBatch is wired for specific attribute and uniform names:

At the top of your vertex shader, add this to define your vertex attributes and varyings (which your linked shader doesn't need because it's relying on built-in variables that aren't available in GL ES):

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord[5];
```

Then in the vertex shader, change the `gl_Position` line to

```
gl_Position = a_position; //since we can't rely on built-in variables
```

and replace all occurrences of `gl_TexCoord` with `v_texCoord` for the same reason.

In the fragment shader, to be compatible with OpenGL ES, you need to declare precision. You also need to declare the same varying, so add this to the top:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
varying vec2 v_texCoord[5];
```

As with the vertex shader, replace all occurrences of `gl_TexCoord` with `v_texCoord`. And also replace all occurrences of `rubyTexture` with `u_texture`, which is the texture name that SpriteBatch uses.

I think that's everything. I didn't actually test this and I'm going off of memory, but hopefully it gets you close.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i got my shaders like this http://pastebin.com/88rmNgVf and get no erros anymore, but all i get is a black screen, can you test it?

Comment: Assuming you followed my way of drawing the quad to the screen, you either need to remove the `u_projTrans` from your shader, or set the SpriteBatch's projection matrix to identity. That's the only issue I initially see.

Comment: The shader is working now, although, the textures still get shaded apart from each other except of the whole screen getting shaded, maybe this is because of the TiledMapRenderer. The whole purpose is that everything rendered in the screen needs to be one texture, i managed to do that and than that texture needs a shader. I think it's because the TiledMap gets skipped.

Comment: Are you drawing to a FrameBuffer using default shader and then drawing that to screen?

Comment: Its working now, the shader didnt sets Alpha to 1.0 so the textures dont get Alpha blending, thanks!